# CSS3 - target elements with more than one data attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML

```
<ul>
   <li data-facet="categories" data-value="full-time">1</li>
   <li data-facet="attendance" data-value="full-time">2</li>
</ul>
```

I need to target the list item with `data-facet="categories"` and `data-value="full-time"`

I've tried the following:

```
li[data-facet="categories"]+[data-value="full-time"]{
   background-color: #ee2d24;
}
```

But this didn't work. For some reason it changed the background colour of the attendance list item :/

Comment: Because you are using `+` which will select the adjacent element of the matched element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, simply chain both attribute selectors together without anything separating them, much like how you would chain attributes, classes or IDs to a type selector:

```
li[data-facet="categories"][data-value="full-time"]
```

> For some reason it changed the background colour of the attendance list item :/

That's because the `+` actually selects the next sibling element, which is *also* represented by the `[data-value="full-time"]`, *separately* from the `li[data-facet="categories"]`. Spacing them out and adding the otherwise-implied universal selector makes this a little bit clearer:

```
li[data-facet="categories"] + *[data-value="full-time"]
```

The selectors that correspond to each element are as follows:

```
<li data-facet="categories" data-value="full-time">1</li> <!-- li[data-facet="categories"] -->
<li data-facet="attendance" data-value="full-time">2</li> <!-- [data-value="full-time"] -->
```

Comment: Thank you BoltClock. I'll accept this answer as it offers useful extra information. But thank you to @Fabrizio Calderan for the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just chain the attributes, without spaces or other symbols in between

```
li[data-facet="categories"][data-value="full-time"]{
   background-color: #ee2d24;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJRWvW

Comment: OP: The original selector you were using was selecting `[data-facet="attendance"]` because it's after `li[data-facet="categories"]`. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Thank you. I tried chaining them on my first attempt but it didn't work, so I tried the + operator as it did at least change the colour. I think it's because list items are added in AJAX so there was a bit of caching going on. All is well now :)